# Angular Jhipster - How to send x-csrf token in all http requests?

Tags: angularjs, csrf, jhipster

I generate an app from hipster generator and create a new factory to call my services.

All the existing services are called with x-csrf token in the headers  but when i try to make a Get or a Post with my factory, i get de error **401**, **Unauthorized**

In my app config, i have this:

```
 //enable CSRF
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'CSRF-TOKEN';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN';
```

This is my factory:

```
angular.module('jhipsterApp')
    .factory('WalletsService', function ($http) {
        return {
            findAll: function () {
                return $http.get('api/walletslist/').then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

When i execute findAll function, i get this error:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) (walletslist, line 0)
```

The x-csrf is saved in cookies but how i pass it in the headers?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at SecurityConfiguration, /api/** requires authentication, so your endpoint requires it too. It's not a CSRF issue, it's just that you must be logged in.

If api/walletslist has to be public, you must do this in SecurityConfiguration

```
.antMatchers("/api/walletslist").permitAll()
```

**Warning**: order matters and make sure your authorizations URLs matches your angular services and REST controller request mappings. It's easy to forget a final slash character in one place.

Any reason why you want to use $http, why not using $resource like other JHipster services?

Comment: Have you tried to run `yo jhipster:entity walletslist` to generate a working service with REST controller and get rid of the code you don't need?

Comment: I can get differents $resources api in my factory? When i see the generated services code, all sevices has the same api path and i need differents path for each function so i call $http instead of $resource

Comment: If you need different paths and you can't use only actions to solve this then your API is probably not REST; Have you tried to remove the final / in $http.get('api/walletslist/') ?

Comment: The problem is that this is not a jhipster issue and you show only a part of your code, so you can't get help

Comment: I haven't tried to run that code. My ideia about create a factory is to create my custom functions without logic of $resource. In this case,  wallet service, i can make a get, update, create and delete but if i need to add a function to change wallet status. Should i create a custom function or use update method? In last case, i need to pass the desired status in the request params and i dont see that in the request params. Did you understand my issue?

Comment: problem solved... i had remove the final "/" and now it's working! thanks